# How can I make multiple styling for only one prop in React Styled Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using Styled Components in react, and I want to wrap all the styles I want for only one prop (it's a conditional prop). Right now I have something like this:

```
<ContentSty
    flexDirection={abilityScores ? "column" : "row"}
    flexWrap={abilityScores ? "no-wrap" : "wrap"}
    cardDisplay={abilityScores ? "flex" : "block"}
    cardHeight={abilityScores ? "auto" : "5rem"}
    cardTextMargin={abilityScores ? "auto 0.5rem" : "0.2rem 0"}
    hoverShadow={abilityScores ? "none" : "0px 0px 14px gold"}
    hoverCursor={abilityScores ? "auto" : "pointer"}
>
```

I always do the same check: if the variable `abilityScores === true` then have this value, else have this other one. Then, in my styles, I have a lot of `some-css-prop: ${(props) => props.someProp};` and it gets kind of messy

Is there a way to just wrap all the styles for `abilityScores === true` in one prop, then just pass a unique prop like `abilityScore={abilityScore === true ? allTheseStylings : ''}`, or a cleaner way, instead of just making a lot of props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation on `StyleObjects` here: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#style-objects

You can use the `props` of `abilityScore` to conditionally style your component.

For example:

```js
const ContentSty = styled.div(props => ({
  flexDirection: props.abilityScores ? "column" : "row",
  flexWrap: props.abilityScores ? "no-wrap" : "wrap",
  cardDisplay: props.abilityScores ? "flex" : "block",
  cardHeight: props.abilityScores ? "auto" : "5rem",
  cardTextMargin: props.abilityScores ? "auto 0.5rem" : "0.2rem 0",
  hoverShadow: props.abilityScores ? "none" : "0px 0px 14px gold",
  hoverCursor: props.abilityScores ? "auto" : "pointer",
});

...

<ContentSty abilityScores={true} />
```